# jQuery form doesn't validate when button is outside of form tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I can't seem to get my form to validate when the button is outside the `<form></form>` tag. Any ideas how I can achieve this? I can't place it inside the form for technical reasons (it's inside a sticky navbar).

My HTML markup:

```
<form id="frm-shipping" class="frm-shipping" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="contact_phone"  class="has_validation" 
  placeholder="Contact phone" value="" data-validation="required" 
  data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >

  <input type="text" name="first_name"  class="has_validation" 
  placeholder="First Name" value="" data-validation="required" 
  data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >

</form>

<button class="btn" onclick="nextStep();">Next</button>
```

And the jQuery code:

```
function nextStep()
{   

    $.validate({    
        form : '#frm-shipping',    
        borderColorOnError:"#FF0000",
        onError : function() {      
        },      
        onSuccess : function() { 

          var params = $( "#frm-shipping").serialize(); 
          // AJAX call here

        }  
    });
}
```

When I click the button, nothing happens. Simply nothing :( Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggested to use onsubmit before but that won't work. As @BenM suggests - the code seems fine as in "nothing happens" is a valid result with this implementation.

Comment: Because, aside from serializing the form, you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: I remove the part that does something because its irrelevant. When I put the button inside the form, it works. When I move it outside, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the button to the form with `form` attribute. See [W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp).

```
<button class="btn" form="frm-shipping" onclick="nextStep();">Next</button>
```

```js
function nextStep()
{   
    $.validate({    
        form : '#frm-shipping',    
        borderColorOnError:"#FF0000",
        onError : function() {   
          console.log('error')
        },      
        onSuccess : function() { 
          console.log('te3st')
          var params = $( "#frm-shipping").serialize(); 
          // AJAX call here

        }  
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>



<form id="frm-shipping" class="frm-shipping" method="post">

  
  <input type="text" name="contact_phone"  class="has_validation" 
  placeholder="Contact phone" value="" data-validation="required" 
  data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >

  <input type="text" name="first_name"  class="has_validation" 
  placeholder="First Name" value="" data-validation="required" 
  data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >

  
  
</form>

<button class="btn" form='frm-shipping' onclick="nextStep();">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
        Validate method
  });
```